# What items are 100% totally useless when you have all DLC?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

All the lists I found include things like Coffee Mugs which aren't actually useless because you can give them to Muggy. I haven't found any lists that are up-to-date for all DLC.

What items can I definitely throw away? I.E. What items can't be used for crafting, can't be traded with NPCs for useful items, and aren't used in quests?

Comment: Does selling the item for a small amount of caps count?

Comment: No, most of them are worth too little for them to be justify the carry weight.

Comment: Ohhhh, DLC! Okay that's a much better question. Wish I could retract my close vote.

Comment: @SaintWacko You should be able to.

Comment: Oh, hey, I can! How long has that been there?

Comment: I don't think there are many items that are completely useless and who's weight to price ratio is too big to be worth picking up. The only thing I can think of are the various clipboards. A lot junk is useful in someway or in other. For example, bent cans can be used in at least one quest.  Pencils are only worth 1 cap, but they're weightless making them as good to carry around as as caps. (btw. Coffee mugs can also be used to make coffee.) My advice would simply be to ignore any common junk that you don't know the purpose for. If you do find a purpose for it, you can easily find more.

Comment: Clipboards can actually be given to the book chute. There are some items that are totally useless. Like ashtrays and hammers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the list of completely unusable items (which means they serve only decoration purpose - no crafting, quests, dialogues, nothing else). I'm not 100% sure the list is complete (maybe 99%) - there might be an error or two.

### **BASE**

- 10 Ball
- 13 Ball
- 2 Ball
- 5 Ball
- 8 Ball
- Acoustic guitar
- Ashtray
- Baseball
- Baseball glove
- Basketball
- <strike>Bent tin can</strike>
- Big spoon
- Brahmin skull
- Brotherhood of Steel holotag
- Centaur blood
- Chessboard
- Cigarette
- Counterfeit bottle cap
- Crutch
- Cuddles' toy car
- Cue ball
- Cup
- Cutting board
- Damaged garden gnome
- Deathclaw hand
- Dinky the T-Rex souvenir
- Dino toy
- Dog bowl
- Doggie treat
- Drinking glass
- Empty jet inhaler
- Evil gnome
- Finger
- Garden gnome
- Gecko egg
- Golden gecko egg
- Golf ball
- Hammer
- Harmonica
- Infected brahmin meat
- Intact garden gnome
- Lawn mower blade
- Leaf blower
- Motorcycle gas tank
- Motorcycle handbrake
- Mutilated arm
- Mutilated leg
- Mutilated organs
- Mutilated skull
- Mutilated torso
- Nuka-Cola truck
- Ophthalmoscope
- Paint gun
- Paperweight
- Ping pong ball
- Plunger
- Pool ball
- Rake
- Scissors
- Sheet music book
- Shot glass
- Spatula
- Spork
- Sunset Sarsaparilla deputy badge
- Tanned gecko hide
- Toy car
- Triangle
- Vacuum cleaner
- Whet stone
- Wood chipper

### **DEAD MONEY**

- Embalming fluid
- Gold bar

### **HONEST HEARTS**

- Green gecko eggs
- Scripture

### **OLD WORLD BLUES**

- Broken detonator
- Deactivated bomb collar

### **LONESOME ROAD**

- Seymour
- Tunneler hide

Comment: That's a whole lot of items to collect.

Comment: The "Bent tin can" can be turned in as part of the unmarked "Dealing with Contreras" quest.

Comment: Nice. I got thrown off a couple times going through that list, as some of those items had a use in Fallout 3, but no longer do in New Vegas.

Comment: Your list is very wrong, gold bars from dead money are worth considerable caps and several of your items are craftable if the correct craft mods are installed, but with just sticking to vanilla i am pretty sure that for instance the scissors are used to make doctor bags. So with that said your whole list is in question cause as i look at it more i see other items that I craft with but my game is heavily modded for crafting and survival in hardcore mode which makes it difficult to just comment on vanilla game.

Comment: I think with the added caveat that everything in this list can be safely sold (as opposed to thrown away), this is a good list. Mods really shouldn't be taken into account, as not everyone can use them. Doctor's bags don't use scissors, they use forceps and scalpels but not scissors.